# The method setDefaultPushCallback from the type PushService is deprecated using android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push, deprecated

I am newbie in android. I have been dealing with the problem of `deprecated method` at `push service` using `parse` services. I have followed similar question for the similar problem here but can't get the solution. In My main `application class` i am dealing with this problem, the code is given below for that one.

```
public class MApplication extends Application {
    private static MApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;
        Parse.initialize(this, JNI.stringFromJNI001(), JNI.stringFromJNI010());

        // Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainLandingActivity.class);
// setDefaultPushCallback shows deprecated method here..

     ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    }

    public static MApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

}
```

In my `manifest` i am using this one:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />


        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

From this *link*  https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/app-crash-on-push-test i saw that i have to use it like the following method, but i cant figure it out how to use this and resolve my problem.

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Please help me for this problem. You help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback()` is deprecated now. All you have to do is to create your own subclass of **ParsePushBroadcastReceiver**. So in your Manifest file along with default Parse push receiver you should declare your Receiver subclass as following

```
 <receiver android:name="com.yourProject.YourReceiver" android:exported=false>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And then your receiver subclass your should override 'getActivity()` method

```
protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivity(Context context,
                                Intent intent) {
    return YourActivity.class;
}
```

Comment: can i use the default class ParsePushBroadcastReceiver to get pushes ?

Comment: @Fakher if you don't need no customizations - you can. If you need any customization - you have to subclass it